# MYSQL XDEVAPI Multiple OR (II) Request

Tags: javascript, mysql, mysql-x-devapi

I'm using the XDEVAPI and trying to use the or(||) statement in javascript, but it seems to break after 1 or/(||) statements, I have 5 separate statuses I'm trying to pull from the DB:

```
.select(['customer_name',
         'account_status',
                  ])
         .where('customer_name like :customer_name && account_status like :account_status || account_status like :account_status || account_status like :account_status')
         .bind('customer_name', customer_name)
         .bind('account_status', 'Some_Status_1')
         .bind('account_status','Some_Status_2')
         .bind('account_status', 'Some_Status_3')
         .execute()
```

Can I use  REGEXP 'Some_Status_1'|Some_Status_2'| etc?

If so what would the syntax be?

Or is there another method that I am missing.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the issue is related to `OR` per se but to the fact that you are using duplicate placeholders. CRUD style APIs use named parameters, as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/parameter-binding.html). By calling `bind('account_status', 'something')` multiple times, you are simply replacing the last value of the `account_status` placeholder.

To do what you want (I think), you need to use different placeholder names. For instance:

```
.select(['customer_name', 'account_status'])
  .where('customer_name like :customer_name && account_status like :account_status1 || account_status like :account_status2 || account_status like :account_status3')
  .bind('customer_name', customer_name)
  .bind('account_status1', 'Some_Status_1')
  .bind('account_status2', 'Some_Status_2')
  .bind('account_status3', 'Some_Status_3')
  .execute()
```

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI connector for Node.js

Comment: This worked perfectly except with the new update and to get the results right I added a parenthesis  inline ` .where('customer_name like :customer_name && (account_status like :account_status1 || account_status like :account_status2 || account_status like :account_status3)') `

Comment: Operator precedence rules are the typical ones, I guess. But what do you mean by “except with the new update”? Is the behavior broken somehow?

Comment: Rui, I guess to say that I updated the NPM package and then added the parenthesis it worked. Not sure if it was a javascript syntax problem or part of the update but it works great now. Have another question coming soon.